# Handlebar size options

Tags: road-bike, handlebars

I was given few options to choose the handlebar size for my future road bike. The frame size is 60cm but for the handlebar I have these options:

40x90,40x100,42x100,42x110,**44x110,44x120**

I measured myself from shoulder to shoulder and it's 44cm, so there are only two options for me. The problem is that I don't know what the second number mean.

The bike is for daily use and some events/triathlons, but most of all is for daily use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these are Drop handlebars, the second dimension would be reach or drop.

On the other hand, as you're buying a complete bike, not just bars, the second dimension is very likely to be **stem length**.

Comment: Thanks @Emyr. asuming is either of those.. for a person like me 190cm tall and for a 60cm frame. what will the ride more comfortable 110 or 120?

Comment: Ok, looking at the picture of the handlebar. it seems it has the stem integrated. I still don't know how to decide between 110 or 120.

Comment: You really have to try it. 190cm tall doesn't determine your torso length or flexibility or arm length.

Comment: Thanks @Batman. I'm very flexible and with the arms extended to both sides, from middle finger to middle finger, is about 200cm. I can't try it first as I'm buying it online.

Comment: It's a complete coin flip, but if you want a number from random idiot on the net, 120cm stem. It's no guarantee, but in general taller riders use longer stems. 110cm would be "short" for someone 190cm. But that is just a wild guess. Do you have a current setup you like to compare it with?

Comment: as important, different people differ in the ratio of inseam to torse length - I have a friend who's 5cm shorter than me but longer in the leg. I can ride his bikes, but they're very uncomfortable.

Comment: This is the where an experienced bike shop can give you guidance. It is best determined by a proper fitting rather than a best guess.